# npm installation error in the VS Code editor

Tags: npm

I am going to install npm and facing this error

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/material-moment-adapter@17.0.4
npm ERR! Found: @angular/material@17.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!   @angular/material@"^17.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/material@"^17.0.2" from nextsapien-component-lib@1.0.27     
npm ERR!   node_modules/nextsapien-component-lib
npm ERR!     nextsapien-component-lib@"^1.0.27" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/material@"17.0.4" from @angular/material-moment-adapter@17.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter
npm ERR!   @angular/material-moment-adapter@"^17.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/material@17.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!   peer @angular/material@"17.0.4" from @angular/material-moment-adapter@17.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter
npm ERR!     @angular/material-moment-adapter@"^17.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I am going to install npm to run the project so I am expecting that it should be installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to install the dependencies using

> npm install --legacy-peer-deps

command or you can try

> npm install --force

command too.

This error occurs because your node version or npm version is supported with your **package.json** file.